# No me muestra checkbox creado dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un control de acceso con una lista de `checkbox` con los diferentes menús. Si en el HTML pongo la lista, me muestra los `checkbox` sin problema. Sin embargo si los agrego desde JavaScript, solo me muestra la lista en texto, sin los `checkbox`.

```
$('#ULmenuAcceso').empty();
var sMenu = "";
for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

    if (data.d[i].lSubMenu.length > 0) {
        sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].id + "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><label><input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].id + "' id='" + data.d[i].id + "'> " + data.d[i].Nombre + "</label></a>";


        sMenu += "<ul class='interior' style='list-style:none'>";
        for (j = 0; j < data.d[i].lSubMenu.length; j++) {


            if (data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu.length > 0) {
                sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><label><input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "' id='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "' /> " + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].Nombre + " </label></a></li>";
                sMenu += "<ul class='interior' style='list-style:none'>";
                for (h = 0; h < data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu.length; h++) {

                    sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu[h].id + "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><label> " + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu[h].Nombre + "</label></a><input type='checkbox' name='list' id='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu[h].id + "' /></li>";

                }
                sMenu += "</ul>";
            } else {
                sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i><label ><input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "' id='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "' /> " + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].Nombre + "</label></a></li>";
            }

        }
        sMenu += "</ul>";
    } else {
        sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].id + "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i><label><input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].id + "' id='" + data.d[i].id + "' /> " + data.d[i].Nombre + "</label></a>";

    }
    sMenu += "</li>";

    $('#ULmenuAcceso').append(sMenu);
```

Así es cómo se ve:

[image: lista de elementos]

Comment: Puede que veas el fallo si usas un depurador (como el Firebug de Firefox) para ver si falla alguna instrucción de Javascript. O incluso si Javascript no da error, talvez veas algo raro en cómo se ha modificado el HTML tras la ejecución

Comment: Parece que tienes un error en lo que estas generando...

Comment: Gracias por contestar...la función no me genera errores, si enlista los resultados pero solo no muestra los checkbox, ...si cambio el tipo del input a text si lo muestra.....y si  lo que se genera en la variable sMenu lo  copio al html, si los muestra...alguna idea de que podría ser? gracias!

Comment: Debes mirar si te hace falta alguna etiqueta de la estructura del de la lista html, debe iniciar desde ul.

Comment: Copia el HTML generado y usa una pagina para ver si todas las etiquetas están correctamente cerradas.
http://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/
Puede que eso te ayude a detectar en tu codigo que está fallando. A mi me ha funcionado más de una vez.

Comment: El código me [funciona sin ningún tipo de problemas](https://jsfiddle.net/rz5nt637/). Los checkboxes se generan bien y se ven, ¿puede ser que haya algo en el CSS que hace que se oculten los checkboxes en algunos casos?¿Usas bootstrap?¿qué versión?

Answer (score 2):

Me da la impresión de que te has olvidado de la llave que cierra el primer `for`, justo antes del `$('#ULmenuAcceso').append(sMenu)`.

Prueba así:

```
var sMenu = "";
for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

  if (data.d[i].lSubMenu.length > 0) {
    sMenu +=
      "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].id + "\");return false;'>" +
      "<i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><label><input type='checkbox'" +
      " name='" + data.d[i].id + "' id='" + data.d[i].id + "'> " + data.d[i].Nombre +
      "</label></a>";

    sMenu += "<ul class='interior' style='list-style:none'>";

    for (j = 0; j < data.d[i].lSubMenu.length; j++) {
      if (data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu.length > 0) {
        sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" +
          data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "\");return false;'>" +
          "<i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><label>" +
          "<input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id +
          "' id='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "' /> " + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].Nombre +
          " </label></a></li>";
        sMenu += "<ul class='interior' style='list-style:none'>";
        for (h = 0; h < data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu.length; h++) {
          sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" +
            data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu[h].id + "\");return false;'>" +
            "<i class='fa fa-caret-right' aria-hidden='true'></i><label> " +
            data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu[h].Nombre + "</label></a>" +
            "<input type='checkbox' name='list' id='" +
            data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].lSubSubMenu[h].id + "' /></li>";
        }
        sMenu += "</ul>";
      } else {
        sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id +
          "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
          "<label ><input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id +
          "' id='" + data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].id + "' /> " +
          data.d[i].lSubMenu[j].Nombre + "</label></a></li>";
      }
    }
    sMenu += "</ul>";
  } else {
    sMenu += "<li><a href='#' onclick='expandeContrae(\"" + data.d[i].id +
      "\");return false;'><i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i>" +
      "<label><input type='checkbox' name='" + data.d[i].id + "' id='" +
      data.d[i].id + "' /> " + data.d[i].Nombre + "</label></a>";

  }
  sMenu += "</li>";
} // <--- Esta llave

$('#ULmenuAcceso').append(sMenu);
```

Lo he probado con un fiddle, y funciona bien: https://jsfiddle.net/9t6w1uvt/